# What's the clojurific way to materialize a function into a map?

Tags: clojure

I am getting started with Clojure and often finding myself 'materializing' a mapping by making a sequence of key-value pairs and feeding them into a map:

```clj
(defn my-function [x] (* x 10))
(def my-function-domain [1 2 3 4 5])

(into {} (map (fn [x] [x (my-function x)]) my-function-domain))
; {1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}

; equivalently
(into {} (map #(vector % (my-function %)) my-function-domain))
```

Before I put that in a utility function for myself, is there a more idiomatic/performant way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: That's what `into` and `map` do - it looks like you understand them and are using them correctly. Without knowing more about what you're actually trying to do, there doesn't seem to be a lot to add here.

Comment: I'm mostly wondering if there's a more succinct way in the standard library where I don't have to explicitly construct entries myself. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to approach this. Here are the two approaches I would probably reach for first:

```
user=> (defn my-function [x] (* x 10))
#'user/my-function
user=> (def my-function-domain [1 2 3 4 5])
#'user/my-function-domain
user=> (zipmap my-function-domain (map my-function my-function-domain))
{1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
user=> (into {} (map (juxt identity my-function)) my-function-domain)
{1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
```

`zipmap` is a useful function to produce a hash map from a sequence of keys and a sequence of corresponding values. I think it represents the "materialize" semantics well.

`juxt` is a useful function for producing a vector of the result of calling multiple functions on a single value. I use `map` with `juxt` quite a lot when I want to walk a collection once and produce pairs from each element (and pour the result into a hash map). It's useful, for example, when you have a sequence of hash maps such as a result set from a database query, and you want a hash map from the primary keys to the rows they are in: `(juxt :id identity)`.

Note that in my second example `map` has just one argument: the function to apply; and `into` has three arguments: the "to" collection, the transform to apply, and the "from" collection. This approach uses the concept of transducers to avoid producing intermediate lazy sequences (the `zipmap` approach -- and your original code -- produce a lazy sequence of the results of my-function, and then consume that to produce the result). Using the transducer-based approach is often faster than producing intermediate lazy sequences, especially for large sequences.

Comment: These are just the sort of alternatives I was looking for. Thanks!

I need to learn transducer idioms. Coming from functional, they are familiar but with enough differences to trip me up.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [`zipmap`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/zipmap) is idiomatic and concise.

The `zipmap` function takes two sequences: one for keys and another for values, and it returns a map where the first sequence provides the keys and the second sequence provides the values.

```clj
(zipmap my-function-domain (map my-function my-function-domain))
; => {1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
```

If you're looking for an even shorter version, you can leverage the [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) function with a map literal combined with a [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) comprehension:

```clj
(into {} (for [x my-function-domain] [x (my-function x)]))
; => {1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
```

Reducing the number of intermediate sequences or collections should, in theory, provide some improvement in performance. Using [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) can be a direct way of constructing the map without producing intermediate sequences:

```clj
(reduce (fn [m x] (assoc m x (my-function x))) {} my-function-domain)
; => {1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
```

Here, the reduce function starts with an empty map (`{}`) and continually associates the next key-value pair into it.

Even faster can be using transients or java interop. To properly check performance [Criterium benchmarking](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) can be used.

Comment: Just to show your `reduce` example using transients: `(persistent! (reduce (fn [m x] (assoc! m x (my-function x))) (transient {}) my-function-domain))`

Answer (score 1):

you could also use something like this:

```
(update-vals (zipmap my-function-domain my-function-domain) my-function)
;;=> {1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
```

you just make a map of {Dom: Dom} and then update each map value with the result of application of `f`.

I don't really know whether it is more or less readable than good old map + reduce (or `into` in this case), but it shows nice clojure util.

Comment: Very concise; great option!